# Python: Reading a .sas7bdat file stored on a remote server

Tags: python, sas, filepath, unc

I am trying to read the contents of a .sas7bdat file living on a remote server. I have no problem reading the file if it is stored locally or I am reading it from the same drive. For testing purposes, it is being tested locally and come time of production, it'll be on the server.

`with SAS7BDAT('file_path_of_remoteFile') as dataset:`

This is the statement in which I need a UNC file path (possibly). I have trouble identifying the correct file path.

I have tried:

```
username@server

username@server.subdomain.net

file:///username@server

file:///server

file:///server.subdomain.net

//server.subdomain.net
```

None of which actually work. Any ideas or alternative solutions??

Comment: It doesn't work that way. It only reads local files. The path is passed to `open()`, which only work with local files. You'll have to download it first. That can be done programmatically, but is a solved problem outside the scope of this question.

Comment: Windows or Linux? Also @JimStewart is right.

Comment: @loa_in_ Windows. So I am required to store the file locally then?

Comment: @JimStewart if I were to deploy my application on a cloud platform, I'd never be able to access the datasets. Downloading them would be too slow because the datasets could be several GBs. Is there a better approach to what I am doing? For example, saving the datasets as a csv and then reading it that way with another Python package?

Comment: They have to be on your machine either way if you are to process them, or at least chunks of them would have to be.

Comment: The best solution is to modify SAS7BDAT to accept URLs and/or IO streams. If downloading is prohibitively expensive, that might be your only option.

Comment: As @loa_in_ mentioned, if the file needs to be randomly accessed, you'd need a local copy.

Comment: @JimStewart what if I make a remote call to a python program that then reads and returns the dataset. The dataset would be local in relation to the python program that is being called remotely. That seems possible.